# How to make <nav> horizontal not vertical on Nextjs using tailwind

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

```
import { Inter } from "@next/font/google";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export default function Nav() {
  return (
    <nav className="bg-gray-800, bg-slate-900">
      <div className="container mx-auto px-6 py-4 flex flex-wrap">
        <div className="px-4 py-2 rounded-lg text-white hover:bg-gray-700">
          {" "}
          <a href="/">Home</a>
        </div>
        <div className="px-4 py-2 rounded-lg text-white hover:bg-gray-700">
          <a href="/jobs">Jobs</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

I have this and it is not showing as horizontally but vertically. How can I change this to horizontal?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that could be done using flexbox, or grid; both of which are built into TailwindCSS. In your case it would look something like this:

```html
<nav className=" flex flex-row ...">
    <!-- your nav content -->
</nav>
```

You can read more on flexbox and how to use Tailwind CSS for your layouts [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-basis).